# Multiple conditions in if

Tags: linux, shell

```
    [ -r "$df" ] && {   
        tail -1 $df | grep "$was_fallback" > /dev/null     
        [ $? -ne 0 ] && { continue; }
```

This is part of a larger code. I am reading some old codes written by seniors. And then I found this piece of code.
I know that [ ] is for 'if' condition. But what is this {} used for?

Comment: I guess there is a missing `}`. The one of the first line is not matched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I know that [ ] is for 'if' condition
```

No. It's not the *if* condition. `[` is the test command. More about it here:

**[What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)**

```
what is this {} used for?
```

It's called **[command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping)**. From the GNU manual:

```
{}

    { list; }

    Placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be
    executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created. 
    The semicolon (or newline) following list is required.
```

Comment: so, using && here will make both [] and {} blocks, to run simultaneously or something else will happen?

Comment: `[]` and `{}` are not blocks. They are not the same and do different functions. In your code, the person wrote it doesn't want the second part ( with `{}`) to run in the same shell's context. They can't run *simultaneously* as `&&` requires the LH side to be executed first and execute the RH side *only* if the LH side returns *true*. So `[]` runs first and then `{}` part runs if `[]` part is true.

Comment: Just to reinforce the `if` command: `if` operates based on the exit status of [its "test-commands"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs). For example, to test if a file has a given pattern, you could write: `if grep -q pattern file; then echo has pattern; else echo no match; fi` -- no square brackets at all but valid syntax.